# Program ATtiny45 with Atmel Studio and Arduino ISP

Tags: arduino, avr, attiny, isp, atmel-studio

Is it possible for me to somehow upload the application I have written with C++ in Atmel Studio with the [Arduino ISP](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) that I can use in the Arduino [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)?

I have no idea how to do this, and I also have no idea where to set the fuses and what to set them to (I want to use the 8 MHz internal clock).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [AVRDUDE](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/). It will allow you to specify files for writing and verifying flash and EEPROM, as well as values for fuses. You will need to use a number of command line arguments, an example of which is given at [Adafruit's ArduinoISP tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/arduinoisp#bonus-using-with-avrdude). Simply replace the [*partno* argument](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html#Option-Descriptions) with `t45` to target the ATtiny45.

As for the fuses, use the [Engbedded Atmel AVR® Fuse Calculator](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc) to figure them out. Pick a device, enter the current settings into the entry boxes at the bottom, change the desired options in the configuration boxes above, and write the new fuse values to the chip.